# Spring maven application terminates immediately after application context is loaded

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, applicationcontext

I have created a maven project and trying to integrate the Spring MVC part in it. I have created a main class which loads the Spring application context. But the issue is, the class terminates immediately after the context gets loaded.I am not able to figure out the issue. Below is the basic required project structure and code,

**Project structure-**

[image]

**pom.xml-**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.ticker.demo</groupId>
<artifactId>stock-market-ticker</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>stock-market-ticker</name>
<description>Nifty 50 stock market ticker</description>

<properties>
    <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    <spring.version>5.2.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <activemq.version>5.15.12</activemq.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- Activemq dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.activemq</groupId>
        <artifactId>activemq-all</artifactId>
        <version>5.15.12</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>
```

**web.xml-**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>Stock market ticker</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>stockmarketticker</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>stockmarketticker</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/stockmarketticker-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

**stockmarketticker-servlet.xml-**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"   
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 

   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.2.xsd">

   <context:component-scan base-package="com.ticker.demo" />
   <import resource="classpath:stock-market-ticker-context.xml" />
   <mvc:annotation-driven/>
</beans>
```

**stock-market-ticker-context.xml-**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ticker.demo" />
    <context:annotation-config />
    <bean id="stockMarketTickerProducer" class="com.ticker.demo.producer.StockMarketTickerProducer" />
</beans>
```

**Main file-**

```
package com.ticker.demo.main;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class StockMarketTickerMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[] { "stock-market-ticker-context.xml" });
        System.out.println("Starting Main...");
        System.out.println("Loaded app context " + context);

    }

}
```

**Output-**

Starting Main...

Loaded app context org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@1a93a7ca, started on Tue Apr 28 15:47:10 IST 2020

And then the application terminates. Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you start your application?

Comment: By executing my main file, StockMarketTickerMain . @MichaelKreutz

Comment: What do you expect? You execute the main method and after finishing successfully it terminates. Do you want to start a web server?

Comment: But if it is a basic maven project, why do I need a web server? Can't it be executed using just the main file, loading the application context? @MichaelKreutz

Comment: If you have a Spring Boot application, then you can start the application and it embeds your application code in a web server (Tomcat by default). But you have setup a plain Spring project, so you could package it as a war file and have to deploy it yourself to a web server. The easier way is probably to turn you project into a Spring Boot project.

Comment: Okay, and If I want to run using a web server then do I need to convert this to a Dynamic web project? @MichaelKreutz

Comment: Suggestion: since ur project as less code, better u can use spring boot

Comment: Then first of all you need a web server :-) And then you can use maven to package your project as a war file which you will have to deploy to the web server.